# Does BigQuery support NUMERIC and DECIMAL data types as defined in ANSI SQL 2011 standard?

Tags: google-bigquery

Many applications, including those that deal with storing data about money, currencies, and other financial information depend on fixed precision decimal data types. In SQL these are stored in columns having NUMERIC or DECIMAL types.

Are there any BigQuery data types that support fixed precision decimals?

Comment: BigQuery supports NUMERIC now (38 digits of precision and 9 decimal digits of scale) https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types

Answer (score 5):

BigQuery supports the [`NUMERIC` data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric-type), which is in beta at the time of this writing. It has 38 total digits of precision, with 9 digits of fractional precision. You can use it in scenarios where precision matters, such as taking the sum or average of monetary values. For example:

```
WITH Transactions AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-05-15' AS transaction_date, NUMERIC '12.34' AS transaction_amount UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-05-01', NUMERIC '100.11' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-05-06', NUMERIC '54.00' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-05-02', NUMERIC '999.99' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-05-03', NUMERIC '1234.56' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-05-04', NUMERIC '99.00'
)
SELECT
  SUM(transaction_amount) AS total_sales,
  ROUND(AVG(transaction_amount), 2) AS average_sale,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(transaction_date AS date, transaction_amount AS amount)
    ORDER BY transaction_amount DESC LIMIT 3
  ) AS top_sales
FROM Transactions;
```

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery supports **BIGNUMERIC** types which have

**Precision:** 76.76 (the 77th digit is partial)

**Scale:** 38

**Min:** -5.7896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968E+38
**Max:** 5.7896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967E+38